# How to establish a SSH MySQL database connection for a Electron App?

Tags: javascript, mysql, ssh, electron

I'm making a app with the Electron Framework, within this the user needs to register an account to be able to use this app.

This worked great when making this for my localhost database, but creating connection with the MySQL server that is running on a dedicated server seems not working for me, and also insecure since people can unpack the `.asar` file and see the database credentials..

So, I've heard about 'SSH Connection' but can't figure out how to set this up, and get this up and running for my Electron app.

I am using XAMPP to create a MySQL/Apache server and I use HeidiSQL to enter the MySQL server.

For your info, I've never used Electron before and this is my first time using it. I've also never used a  SSH connection before *(at least, not that I'm aware of.)* so a guide for newbies would be nice.